# How to show one instance instead of showing three instance in java?

Tags: java, spring

I am coming to an issue where I am showing three instances of object when I do a GET request. All I want to do is show one instance showing in my schema below. (schema is the way I want it). So, can anyone help me solve this issue to just show one instance when I do a GET request? thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you also post the class with main()?

Comment: everything is posted above. what do you mean with main()?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question but I think to get a salary out of many, the following would do.

```
 public Salary retrieveASalary() {
    return salaryRepository.streamAll().findAny().get();
    }
```

Comment: create another method?

Comment: I updated my code. findAny() returns an optional and IMO, .get() on an optional is not a good way to fetch an element from optional but, this will work I think

Comment: should I remove the `Stream<Salary>`

Comment: also getting the same error in my `SalaryController` method `getAllSalaries`